# How to get ans save the images from the json data from server into arraylist?

Tags: android, json

I am facing issue in how to read the image from the server and save the image in the arraylist .
The json data from server is given below

```
{
"DS": {
    "LST": [
        {
            "OID": 1,
            "OCD": "1",
            "OPE": "AIRCEL",
            "IPH": "Images/provider/aircelsm.jpg",
            "MIL": 10,
            "MXL": 10
        },
        {
            "OID": 2,
            "OCD": "3",
            "OPE": "AIRTEL",
            "IPH": "Images/provider/airtelsm.jpg",
            "MIL": 10,
            "MXL": 10
        },
        {
            "OID": 4,
            "OCD": "4",
            "OPE": "BSNL",
            "IPH": "Images/provider/bsnlsm.jpg",
            "MIL": 10,
            "MXL": 10
        },
        {
            "OID": 6,
            "OCD": "5",
            "OPE": "DOCOMO",
            "IPH": "Images/provider/docomosm.jpg",
            "MIL": 10,
            "MXL": 10
        },
        {
            "OID": 7,
            "OCD": "6",
            "OPE": "IDEA",
            "IPH": "Images/provider/ideasm.jpg",
            "MIL": 10,
            "MXL": 10
        },
        {
            "OID": 8,
            "OCD": "7",
            "OPE": "MTS",
            "IPH": "Images/provider/mtssm.jpg",
            "MIL": 10,
            "MXL": 10
        },
        {
            "OID": 5,
            "OCD": "8",
            "OPE": "RELAINCE",
            "IPH": "Images/provider/reliancesm.jpg",
            "MIL": 10,
            "MXL": 10
        },
        {
            "OID": 3,
            "OCD": "9",
            "OPE": "VODAFONE",
            "IPH": "Images/provider/vodafonesm.jpg",
            "MIL": 10,
            "MXL": 10
        }
    ]
  }
}
```

How to get the image from the server and save the image in arraylist . The arraylist data are viewed in the listview. I tried some methods but the issue is not solved .Please explain the step by step

The tried code for reading the image from server

```
  JSONObject json = null;

                try {
                    json = new JSONObject(result.getResult().toString());
                } catch (JSONException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                // Create the root JSONObject from the JSON string.
                JSONObject jsonRootObject = null;
                jsonRootObject = json.optJSONObject("DS");

                //Get the instance of JSONArray that contains JSONObjects
                JSONArray jsonArray = jsonRootObject.optJSONArray("LST");

                //Iterate the jsonArray and print the info of JSONObjects
                for(int i=0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject jsonObject = null;
                    try {
                        jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    } catch (JSONException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    String iph = null;

                    String oid = jsonObject.optString("OID").toString();
                    String ocd = jsonObject.optString("OCD").toString();
                    String opd = jsonObject.optString("OPE").toString();
                    String mil = jsonObject.optString("MIL").toString();
                    String mxl = jsonObject.optString("MXL").toString();
                    try {
                         iph = jsonObject.getString("IPH").toString();
                    } catch (JSONException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    String urldisplay = "http://192.168.1.105/TotalRecharge/"+iph;
                    Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
                    try {
                        InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
                        mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
                    } catch (Exception e3) {
                        e3.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    SpinnerMenu spinnerData = new SpinnerMenu();
                    spinnerData.setOid(oid);
                    spinnerData.setOcd(ocd);
                    spinnerData.setOpd(opd);
                    spinnerData.setMil(mil);
                    spinnerData.setMix(mxl);
                    spinnerData.setImage(mIcon11);

                    selectedNetwork.add(spinnerData);

                }

            }
```

This is the  code used for to save  the image in arraylist

```
                    String urldisplay = "http://192.168.1.105/TotalRecharge/"+iph;
                    Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
                    try {
                        InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
                        mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
                    } catch (Exception e3) {
                        e3.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

Comment: Could you add your code which you tried?

Comment: wait i will edit my answer

Comment: @  Muthukrishnan Rajendran  i edited my answer

Comment: Are you running this in main thread..?

Comment: You can use **Glide** instead you loading and storing.

Comment: Everything is fine, but your are tryning to access Http in main thread it will crash.

Comment: You can just store the image path in **spinnerData** later while display in UI just use Glide and give the path it will update in UI

Comment: @  Muthukrishnan Rajendran will you post your answer please

Comment: as @Muthukrishnan Ragendran told you can store image url in arraylist and load images using Glide , decoding every images to bitmap can cause outofmemoryexception...

Comment: [Android official doc](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap.html) Android team also recomending glide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of download and storing the image data by yourself, you can just save the image path and you can use `Glide` lib to handle the image.

Just change your setImage(Bitmap) to setImage(String), and just store the path what you get in Json

```
try {
     iph = jsonObject.getString("IPH").toString();
} catch (JSONException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}

String urldisplay = "http://192.168.1.105/TotalRecharge/"+iph;

SpinnerMenu spinnerData = new SpinnerMenu();

spinnerData.setImage(urldisplay);
```

And while loading image just give that to glide

For Glide:

Add this in your build.gradle

```
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.5.2'
```

while displaying the image in UI you can do like this,

```
SpinnerMenu spinnerData = item.get(position)

ImageView imageview = // your image view;

Glide.with(context).load(spinnerData.getImage()).into(imageview);
```